# Oracle substract previous row

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got this query:

```
SELECT user_id, from_loc_id, to_loc_id, to_char(dstamp, 'hh24:mi:ss')
FROM inventory_transaction
WHERE code = 'Pick'
AND substr(work_group,1,6) = 'BRANCH'
AND dstamp BETWEEN to_date('24/02/2022  17:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AND
    to_date('24/02/2022  18:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
ORDER BY user_id;
```

That's the output:

[image]

My expected output is:

[image]

I was trying to use lag, but didn't really worked.
I've just realized I need to add a second ORDER BY, so first by user, second by to_char(dstamp, 'hh24:mi:ss').

All solutions much appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NUMTODSINTERVAL` function with `day` argument and applying `SUBSTR` to extract `hours:minutes:seconds` portion as your data resides within a specific date such as

```sql
SELECT t.user_id, 
       t.dstamp,
       SUBSTR(
              NUMTODSINTERVAL(dstamp - LAG(dstamp) 
                        OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY dstamp),'day'),
              12,8) AS time_diff
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=aad4ba37c4b9b261597d479b5a84086f)</kbd>

**Edit :** The case above is applied for the column `dstamp` is considered to be of ***date*** data type, if its data type is ***timestamp***, then use the following query containing ***date*** *cast* instead

```sql
SELECT t.user_id, 
       t.dstamp,
       SUBSTR(
              NUMTODSINTERVAL(CAST(dstamp AS date) - LAG(CAST(dstamp AS date)) 
                        OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY CAST(dstamp AS date)),'day'),
              12,8) AS time_diff
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=99e3e575fc38712b864d89214645df19)</kbd>

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, unfortunetly i've received that error as an output: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND. I was trying to use CAST but cant really get it work.

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted, thank you very much!

Comment: you're welcome @Komarov . Even [this conversion for timestamp](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b91d908995db11f8a6aaacdce6c59618) is more elegant. Best wishes.